# How can I add an order with POST request in the RESTful Service?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, postman, restful-authentication

I am trying to add an order for customer's panel with JWT authentication.
I activated authorization,add parameters in the body in Postman and send it but "status":422,"errors":"Order no valid"} it gives this message and dev.log file is below.

```
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.791369+02:00] request.INFO: Matched route "order_apiorders_add". {"route":"order_apiorders_add","route_parameters":{"_route":"order_apiorders_add","_controller":"App\\Controller\\OrderController::addOrder"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/api/orders","method":"POST"} []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.823528+02:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"api","authenticators":1} []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.823621+02:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"api","authenticator":"Lexik\\Bundle\\JWTAuthenticationBundle\\Security\\Guard\\JWTTokenAuthenticator"} []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.823697+02:00] security.DEBUG: Calling getCredentials() on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"api","authenticator":"Lexik\\Bundle\\JWTAuthenticationBundle\\Security\\Guard\\JWTTokenAuthenticator"} []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.836138+02:00] security.DEBUG: Passing guard token information to the GuardAuthenticationProvider {"firewall_key":"api","authenticator":"Lexik\\Bundle\\JWTAuthenticationBundle\\Security\\Guard\\JWTTokenAuthenticator"} []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.937527+02:00] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.password AS password_3 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["admin"] []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.949440+02:00] security.INFO: Guard authentication successful! {"token":{"Lexik\\Bundle\\JWTAuthenticationBundle\\Security\\Authentication\\Token\\JWTUserToken":"JWTUserToken(user=\"admin\", authenticated=true, roles=\"ROLE_USER\")"},"authenticator":"Lexik\\Bundle\\JWTAuthenticationBundle\\Security\\Guard\\JWTTokenAuthenticator"} []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.950400+02:00] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator set no success response: request continues. {"authenticator":"Lexik\\Bundle\\JWTAuthenticationBundle\\Security\\Guard\\JWTTokenAuthenticator"} []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.950461+02:00] security.DEBUG: Remember me skipped: it is not configured for the firewall. {"authenticator":"Lexik\\Bundle\\JWTAuthenticationBundle\\Security\\Guard\\JWTTokenAuthenticator"} []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.966109+02:00] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.967877+02:00] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO order (product_id, quantity, address, shipping_date, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"1":1,"2":1,"3":"Levent","4":20,"5":32} []
[2020-08-24T10:31:01.971845+02:00] doctrine.DEBUG: "ROLLBACK" [] []
```

I have two entity classes which are User and Order and User's variables are "username,password,orders(orders variable has a OneToMany relationship and mappedBy="user"). Order's variables are "productId,quantity,address,shippingDate and user(user has a ManyToOne relationship and inversedBy="orders")

My addOrder function is below,

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @Route("/orders", name="orders_add", methods={"POST"})
 */
public function addOrder(Request $request,TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    try{
        $request = $this->transformJsonBody($request);

        if (!$request || !$request->request->get('productId') || !$request->request->get('quantity') || !$request->request->get('address') || !$request->request->get('shippingDate')){
            throw new Exception();
        }

        $user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $order = new Order();

        $order->setProductId($request->get('productId'));
        $order->setQuantity($request->get('quantity'));
        $order->setAddress($request->get('address'));
        $order->setShippingDate($request->get('shippingDate'));
        $order->setUser($user);
        $entityManager->persist($order);
        $entityManager->flush();


        $data = [
            'status' => 200,
            'success' => "Order added successfully",
        ];
        return $this->response($data);

    }catch (Exception $e){
        $data = [
            'status' => 422,
            'errors' => "Order no valid",

        ];
        return $this->response($data, 422);
    }
}
```

In addition,link of github repo is https://github.com/Berkayermis/RESTfulService

I have read lots of articles and talked many people but I am learning REST APIs since last month and I am very newbie on this topic but I want to learn it.

Thanks

Comment: since you have an exception, have you considered logging it or outputting it?!!! maybe there's something in it like "MYSQL ERROR blablabla"

Comment: What @Jakumi said above. Rule of a thumb: whenever you catch an unknown exception, log it with `$logger->critical(....)`. You'll thank yourself later...

Comment: Hello I did it and this error message appears:

"errorInfo": [
                        "42000",
                        1064,
                        "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (product_id, quantity, address, shipping_date, user_id) VALUES (1, 1, '...' at line 1"
                    ]